# How to automate midi and audio settings?

Tags: sound, keyboard, raspberrypi, midi

I have a libre computer roc-rk3328 with Ubuntu 20.04.
I'm using a synth called AMsynth, every time I turn it on I have to:

1. use the command "aconnect" to connect a midi keyboard to the synth.
2. Open the settings manager to verify the sounds comes out of the audio jack instead of the HDMI port.

Since I want to use it without a screen and keyboard my question is:

Is there a way to automate these routines?
So I can just plug and play

Comment: look into udev rules, which allow you to run commands when a device is connected, etc. You can make a rule to run a script that configures the device whenever it's detected.

Comment: I am very new to Linux so this question might sound dumb. How can I do that?

Comment: that's why I said "look into." You will likely have to do some research and testing and debugging in order to get that working, but I was giving you a pointer that `udev` is the way to automate actions when a device is connected. Start by googling "udev rules," possibly along with some specific information about your device.

Comment: stackexchange sites aren't designed for back-and-forth communication. If you will need someone to guide you through the process, try asking on a site designed for those kinds of questions, such as the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/)

Comment: Noted, thanks for the help!